# Android: Listview and Tab view

Tags: android, listview, tabview

I keep having this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(8107): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.KAHTextApp/com.example.KAHTextApp.Main}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.KAHTextApp/com.example.KAHTextApp.Inbox}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

I need some help, when the send button is tapped the message will be saved in the database and the list view will display the details. I used the  [Notepad 3 Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex3.html)  for the database.

Here's the KAHTextApp java:

```
public class KAHTextApp extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    Button btnRecipient;
    Button btnSend;
    EditText editTextRecipient;
    EditText editTextNewMessage;
    Spinner spinnerTimeDelay;

    private static final int CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT = 1001;
    private int count=0;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public boolean FirstLoad = true;

    private MessagesDBAdapter mDbHelper;//
    private Long mRowId;//

    String[] items={"No Delay", "15 seconds", "30 seconds", "60 seconds"};

    Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.compose_message);

        btnRecipient = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_recipient_picker);
        btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
        editTextRecipient = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_recipient);
        editTextNewMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_new_message);
        spinnerTimeDelay = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_delay);

        spinnerTimeDelay.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,items);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerTimeDelay.setAdapter(aa);

        mRowId = (savedInstanceState == null) ? null://
            (Long) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(MessagesDBAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
        if (mRowId==null) {
            Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
            mRowId=extras!=null ? extras.getLong(MessagesDBAdapter.KEY_ROWID):null;
        }

        populateFields();//

        // calls the contact picker
        btnRecipient.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);
            }
        });
    }

    // Spinner
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int pos, long id) {
        count=pos;
        if(FirstLoad){
            FirstLoad = false;
            return;                         
        }

        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You chose " + 
                  parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()+ " to delay", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
          return;
        }

    public  void showProgress () {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setMessage("Sending Message .. ");
        dialog.show(); 
    }

    // Contact Picker    
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (reqCode) {
            case (CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT):

                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    Uri contactData = data.getData();
                    Cursor contactsCursor = managedQuery(contactData,
                            null, null, null, null);
                    if (contactsCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        String id = contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                        String name = contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        String hasPhoneNumber = contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                        sb.append(name);
                        if (Integer.parseInt(hasPhoneNumber) > 0) {
                            Uri myPhoneUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, id);
                            Cursor phoneCursor = managedQuery(
                                    myPhoneUri, null, null, null, null);
                            for (phoneCursor.moveToFirst(); !phoneCursor.isAfterLast(); phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                                String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor
                                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                                sb.append(phoneNumber);
                            }
                        } else {
                            sb.append("This contact doesn't have a phone number");
                        }
                        editTextRecipient.setText(sb.toString());
                    }
                }
                break;
            }


         btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String phoneNo = editTextRecipient.getText().toString();
                String message = editTextNewMessage.getText().toString(); 
                Log.d(phoneNo, message);
                saveState();
                boolean split = false;

                final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                         "Your message " + "\"" + message + "\"" + " is sent to " +"\""+ phoneNo+"\"", 
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                Runnable showToastRunnable = new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      dialog.cancel();
                      toast.show();
                  }
              };

                if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)  {
                    showProgress();
                    if (count == 0) {
                          handler.postDelayed(showToastRunnable, 0);
                      }
                      else if (count == 1) {
                          handler.postDelayed(showToastRunnable, 15000);
                      }
                      else if (count == 2) {
                          handler.postDelayed(showToastRunnable, 30000);
                      }
                      else if (count == 3) {
                          handler.postDelayed(showToastRunnable, 60000);
                      }
                }

                   // sendSMS(phoneNo, message, split); */
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });        
    }

     private void populateFields() {
        if (mRowId!=null) {
            Cursor note=mDbHelper.fetchNote(mRowId);
            startManagingCursor(note);
            editTextRecipient.setText(note.getString(note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MessagesDBAdapter.KEY_RECIPIENT)));
            editTextNewMessage.setText(note.getString(note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MessagesDBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE)));
        }
     }

     protected void onSavedInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        saveState();
        outState.putSerializable(MessagesDBAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        saveState();
     }

     @Override
     protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        populateFields();
     }

     private void saveState() {
         String phoneNo = editTextRecipient.getText().toString();
         String message = editTextNewMessage.getText().toString(); 

        if (mRowId==null) {
            long id=mDbHelper.createNote(phoneNo, message);
        }
     }
```

Here's the inbox, where the list view database is:

```
public class Inbox extends ListActivity {
    ListView ListViewMessageInbox;

    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;

    private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;

    private MessagesDBAdapter mDbHelper;
    private Cursor mNotesCursor;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.inbox);
            mDbHelper = new MessagesDBAdapter(this);
            mDbHelper.open();
            fillData();
            registerForContextMenu(getListView());

        ListViewMessageInbox= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewMessageInbox);
        }

        private void fillData() {
            String[] from = new String[]{MessagesDBAdapter.KEY_RECIPIENT};
            int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};
            SimpleCursorAdapter messages = 
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.message_row, mNotesCursor, from, to);
            setListAdapter(messages);
        }

         @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
                menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_insert);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
                switch(item.getItemId()) {
                    case INSERT_ID:
                        createNote();
                        return true;
                }

                return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
            }

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
            menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId()) {
                case DELETE_ID:
                    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                    mDbHelper.deleteNote(info.id);
                    fillData();
                    return true;
            }
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }

        private void createNote() {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, KAHTextApp.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
            Intent i = new Intent(this, KAHTextApp.class);
            i.putExtra(MessagesDBAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
                    fillData();
        }

}
```

and here's the main where it holds the tab view:

```
public class Main extends TabActivity {

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
        TabSpec secondTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");

        firstTabSpec.setIndicator("Inbox").setContent(new Intent(this,Inbox.class));
        secondTabSpec.setIndicator("New Message").setContent(new Intent(this,KAHTextApp.class));

        tabHost.addTab(firstTabSpec);
        tabHost.addTab(secondTabSpec);

    }
}
```

What do I miss here? Help please.

Answer (score 0):

In your `inbox.xml` layout file, your ListView needs to have this line when you want to use a `ListActivity`

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Answer (score 0):

when you extend listActivity `getListView()` it will search for Listview with id 
`@android:list` .
set it in inbox.xml

Answer (score 0):

**In your R.layout.inbox means inbox.xml file,**

declare a ListView with `android:id="@android:id/list"`